# Python, R and rpy2 c-stack too close to the limit error message

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Edit: I have seen a few answers to this question for people working in UNIX based systems but I am working in windows so I don't think these will work.

I am trying to call R from Python via the rpy2 package, everything seemed to be working fine and then one day I started to get his error, just trying to import rpy2 packages. The code is simply:

```
from rpy2 import robjects as r
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import DataFrame
from rpy2.robjects import Formula 
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
```

And the error message I get is:

Error: C stack usage  24382064 is too close to the limit

Things I've tried so far are:

- Running the file with a random, non rpy2 related import statement, the error does not appear in this case
- I tried to think of a way of turning c-stack checking off from within R (i.e. using R_CStackLimit = -1) but I think this needs to be done for every R session, and as I can't connect to R at all without getting the error I can't send any commands to R.

Would really appreciate some advice, I've been trying to work this out for days and got pretty much nowhere.

Tim

Comment: I think that R_CStackLimit is already set to -1: https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/src/d3076e17d7302f5262e9a93959339572bfc663cd/rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#_rinterface.c-1276

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? been stuck in the same thing !

Comment: I did, but it was quite strange and I am not sure if the solution will apply to your problem. The application I was writing code for was importing rpy2 dynamically if requested by the user and not when the application was kicked off. When I moved the import to happen when the application was kicked off the problem magically went away! Very strange, this error seems to stem from multiple causes, there is obviously more going on under the hood here than I understand...Do let me know if you manage to solve the issue though, I am very curious!